# Can I use a positive and negative Fibonacci scale to measure sustainability for project requests using Weighted Sum (WSM/SAW)?

Tags: multicriteria-decision-analysis

I hope the question is still clear as I'm a little bit over my head with the topic.

I'm trying to measure a sustainability index/score for incoming project requests (alternatives). I'm using the weighted Sum model (WSM). I am considering using the Fibonacci scale (1,2,3,5,8,13,21) to estimate the value of each criterion, but I would like to use both positive and negative numbers to measure that so that the range is from -21 to 21.

The reason is, taking for example "reduction of CO2 emissions" as a criterion, I want to be able to measure if for a specific alternative the CO2 emissions increase or decrease (higher score is better). Is that still possible? All the WSM models I have seen (on academic papers, etc) use a positive scale, as either a benefit or cost criterion.

Also, since I'm technically directly assigning scores to each criterion, do I no longer need to normalise the criteria?

Comment: Your example of CO2 reduction does not indicate a need for negative weights. Assuming your scale is intended to be "higher is better", and you assign a positive weight $w$ to the emission score $x$ with $x>0$ being a reduction and $x<0$ being an increase in emissions, the score $w\cdot x$ will reward emission reductions and penalize emission increases. So the weights stay positive but the variables can be either positive or negative.

Comment: Thanks for your help @prubin. I wasn't trying to find out whether I can assign negative weights (w), but whether I could assign positive and negative values for x. I might have phrased it wrong, but you answered the question nonetheless, thanks. 

But just for clarification, I wouldn't need to normalise it again using maxmin, or linear sum, etc., since using the Fibonacci scale counts as score assessment, right? like the scores for x are normalised and I would just need to do Sum(w*x)?

Comment: If you want the weights to accurately reflect relative importance (e.g., one unit of criterion 3 is as important as one unit each of criteria one and two), then you will want to normalize each criterion so that "one unit" in that comparison makes sense. For instance, if one ton of CO2 emissions is as important as 100 lbs. of capture carbon and 20 planted trees, then you'll want to measure CO2 in tons, carbon in units of 100 lb. and planted trees in multiples of 20.